# How do I install 'rev' in Cygwin?

Tags: installation, cygwin, unix-utils

The Unix rev utility reverses lines in a file. How do I get this under Cygwin? Which package do I need to install?

Answer (score 10):

The package `util-linux` contains `rev`. I found out using the [Debian package search](http://packages.debian.org/).

Comment: Yes, you should be able to run the Cygwin setup utility and find and install util-linux.

Comment: More relevantly, there's the Cygwin package search at http://cygwin.com/packages.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tac` or `sort -r` from GNU coreutils.

Comment: `rev` actually reverts the letters on each line, not the lines in a file.